# Looping array with while get only last value

Tags: java, arrays, android-studio

I have three array

```
int[] image = {R.drawable.img1,R.drawable.img2}    int[] sound= {R.raw.m1,R.raw.m2}    String[] nom ={"el1","el2"}
```

I tryed to change a view with imageview, text from those array when click button but i got only the last value from three array these my method i call when onclick method

```
  private void updateData() {

       while (i<nom.length) {
           ImageView.setImageResource(image[i]);
           textview.setText(nom[i]);
           mysong = MediaPlayer.create(Activity.this, sound[i]);
           mysong.start();
           i++;
       }

}
```

Comment: What is the initial value of `i`? You have mentioned that.

Comment: @AKSingh - I think you meant "You have not mentioned that:".

Comment: @user16632363 Yes, I meant to say that.

Comment: And perhaps it is a typo ImageView.setImageResource(image[ir]);  ir and not i!

Comment: i is inizilized 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this....

```
 Random random = new Random();
 private void updateData() {
       int random_number = random.nextInt(image.length);
       ImageView.setImageResource(image[random_number]);
       textview.setText(nom[random_number]);
       mysong = MediaPlayer.create(Activity.this, sound[random_number]);
       mysong.start();
  }
```

Note : Make Sure Your All Three Array Same Size...

Comment: Thanks but I want they are in ascending order

Comment: Ok..Check my next Ans..

Answer (score 1):

Try this....

```
int anInt = 0;
```

And After OnClick

```
 private void updateData() {
       if (anInt < image.length - 1) {
          anInt++;
       } else {
          anInt = 0;
       }

       ImageView.setImageResource(image[anInt]);
       textview.setText(nom[anInt]);
       mysong = MediaPlayer.create(Activity.this, sound[anInt]);
       mysong.start();
  }
```

Note : Make Sure Your All Three Array Same Size...

Comment: it works but after this activity it must start a new activity. Android start the other activity before i click button.

Comment: Sorry but i can't understand what you are saying...

Comment: Thanks @jay it works. it was a careless mistake